# ViewModel in MVC correct way of accessing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone please tell me whether this is the correct way of creating a viewmodel. I'm using Ninject and the only way I can get the view model to work is with the code below.

Also I cannot seem to be able to pass the data from the viewmodel to the controller unless I create a 2nd interface.

The code below does work, but reading all the examples I have seen I seem to be duplicating a lot off code from my domain layer.

---------------------Code Data access layer------

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Web.Domain.SearchEngine
    {
    public class DisplaySearchResults
        {
        public string Title         { get; set; }
        public string Description   { get; set; }
        public string URL           { get; set; }
        }
    public class GetSearchResults : IGetSearchResults
        {
        private string dbConn;

        public GetSearchResults()
            {
            dbConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Search"].ConnectionString;
            }

        public IEnumerable<DisplaySearchResults> SearchResults(string q, string option, int pagenumber)
            {
            List<DisplaySearchResults> Data = new List<DisplaySearchResults>();
            string spName = "dbo.FTS_On_at_Websites";
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(dbConn))
                {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, cn))
                    {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@strSearchPhrase", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SearchMode", SqlDbType.Int, 4));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@intPageNumber", SqlDbType.Int));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@intRecordsPerPage", SqlDbType.Int));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@intTotalRecordsReturned", SqlDbType.Int));
                    cmd.Parameters["@strSearchPhrase"].Value = q;
                    cmd.Parameters["@SearchMode"].Value = 1;
                    cmd.Parameters["@intPageNumber"].Value = pagenumber;
                    cmd.Parameters["@intRecordsPerPage"].Value = 10;
                    cmd.Parameters["@intTotalRecordsReturned"].Value = 10;

                    cn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
                        {
                        if (rdr.HasRows)
                            {
                            while (rdr.Read())
                                {
                                Data.Add(new DisplaySearchResults
                                {
                                    Title           = (string)rdr["PageTitle"],
                                    Description     = (string)rdr["PageParagraph"],
                                    URL             = (string)rdr["PageURL"]
                                });
                                }
                            }
                        return Data;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

-------------Code ViewModel--------------------

```
    using Microsoft.Security.Application;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Web.Domain.SearchEngine;

namespace Web.UI.ModelHelpers.Search
    {
    public class DisplaySearchResultsViewModel
        {
        public string Title         { get; set; }
        public string Description   { get; set; }
        public string URL           { get; set; }
        }

    public class GetSearchResultsViewModel : IGetSearchResultsViewModel
        {
        private readonly IGetSearchResults _IGSR;
        public GetSearchResultsViewModel(IGetSearchResults IGSR)
            {
            _IGSR = IGSR;
            }

        public IEnumerable<DisplaySearchResultsViewModel> SearchResultsViewModel(string q, string option, int pagenumber)
            {
            var searchResults = _IGSR.SearchResults(q, option, pagenumber).AsEnumerable();

            List<DisplaySearchResultsViewModel> GetData = new List<DisplaySearchResultsViewModel>();

            foreach (var details in searchResults.AsEnumerable())
                {
                GetData.Add(new DisplaySearchResultsViewModel()
                {
                    Title           = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(details.Title),
                    Description     = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(details.Description).ToLower(),
                    URL             = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(details.URL),
                });
                }
            return GetData;
            }
        }
    }
```

In controller I have

```
var DisplaySearchResults    = _IGSR.SearchResultsViewModel(cleanText, "1", 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not the correct way to build a view model. A view model should not contain any data access logic in it. That's the responsibility of the model.

What you should do instead is use Ninject to inject the `IGetSearchResults` instance into your controller instead of having your `GetSearchResultsViewModel` view model take it as constructor dependency. Actually you do not need this `GetSearchResultsViewModel` at all. You already have the correct view model called `DisplaySearchResultsViewModel`. Then it's the responsibility of your controller to use your data access layer and build this view model.

For example:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGetSearchResults repository;
    public SomeController(IGetSearchResults repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult SomeAction(string q, string option, int pagenumber)
    {
        // query your data access layer and build the view model that you will
        // pass to the view
        IEnumerable<DisplaySearchResultsViewModel> model = this.repository
            .SearchResults(q, option, pagenumber)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(details => new DisplaySearchResultsViewModel
            {
                Title = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(details.Title),
                Description = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(details.Description).ToLower(),
                URL = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(details.URL)
            })
            .ToList();

         return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed code, never separated domain and viewmodel, domain code in separate class to viewmodel, my mistake not showing that

Comment: It's good to separate those layer for better readability but I was able to immediately see the mistake of using your data access layer in the view model which is not correct.

Comment: Hi Darin that is how I used to do it, but in a number of books I have been reading the authors say keep the controller light and move all presention i.e in my case Sanitizing data into viewmodel. It does get a bit confusing when some books say one thing and other book etc say something else. its hard to deside which way to go

Comment: Sanitizing is something that should be done inside the view when you display the data, this should not even be part of your server side logic.